# Loading JSON FIle in FileMaker for D3 in WebViewer

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, filemaker

I am trying to implement D3 graphs and charts in a FileMaker solution. I am stuck on loading a JSON file properly to be used in D3 code displayed in the webviewer.

I am loading all JS libraries into global variables ($$LIB.D3.JS, $$LIB.JQUERY.JS, etc.). Then I am placing the HTML code on the layout (giving an object name, i.e. html). The web viewer grabs the HTML code (from a text box on the layout) and JS code (from global variables) to render the page. This all works fine. (I am using this method detailed here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMo7fILZTQs)

However, the D3 code I have uses the getJSON() function to get a JSON, parse the data and create the visualization. I can't figure out a way to get the JSON file as a file from within FileMaker. I could put the content of the JSON file into a FileMaker variable and feed that into the HTML, but I then would not be able to use getJSON(). I would have to redo the D3 code to get the data from a JS variable and parse the data from the variable.

Is there a way for me to load a JSON file so FileMaker could use it to render the visualization properly in the WebViewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have two options.**

**1.** Calc the JSON into the HTML as you mentioned. Your right you will have to change how you load the JSON with d3. But its not tough. When you load the JSON from disk, using something like `d3.json('/data.json', callback)` you are just loading the json and then giving it to the callback function.  If the JSON is in the HTML page in a something like `var embeddedJSON`  You can just call the callback directly with the `embeddedJSON` like

`callback (embeddedJSON)`

Your code may look more like this.

```
d3.json('/data.json', function(data){
   // bunch of d3 code
})
```

The callback in this case is an anonymous function. You can change it like this.

```
var render = function(data){
   // bunch of d3 code
})
// then call render with your json variable that you embedded into the html
render ( embeddedJSON )
```

That will work just fine.

**2.** Export the html page to the temp directory, and export the json file with the data into right next to it. Then display the html using a file://url.  In this case you can use `d3.json(/data.json, callback )` and that will work just fine too.

Each of these methods have their pros and cons, but they both work.

Comment: Does exporting to the temp directory work with FileMaker Go and WebDirect?

Comment: Either of the methods will work on Filemaker Go. Exporting to the temp directory will not work with webdirect. Which is one of the reasons I said they both have pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the best practice for integrating javascript or other assets in a Webviewer is to push assets to the temp directory (get this using GetTemporaryPath() in FileMaker), you can then export assets directly to named files. Once this is done, you can reference these files in your code using the file:// protocol.

This has numerous advantages over older methods, such as loading everything into global variables. One of the biggest of these is that provided you load your JSON into a discrete file and don't "pollute" any other files with FileMaker data, you can work entirely in the code environment of your choice, then simply move web JavaScript libraries, html, CSS, and other assets directly into your FileMaker solution.

Comment: I would not call exporting to the temp directory a best practice. It is a good method. But so is calcing the entire web app as a single html string and displaying it as a data url

Comment: Todd, it's a pity our answers crossed in the ether; I wasn't intending to contradict your post. However, I'll stick to my guns in calling this "a" best practice — and not "the" one true best practice for all cases. I do agree there are cases where the alternate method you describe can be used to excellent effect, but would also point out that in the majority of cases, doing this leads to a series of unfortunate practices that tend to paint developers into an unfortunate corner. At the end of the day, I suspect we agree on about 98% of this turf :-).

Comment: Brian, It may be 2% it maybe more :-) I can't really tell since its not clear what those "unfortunate practices" are that you mention.

But I can tell you that I ship two products that are web viewer based JavaScript apps. Neither one of the exports to the temp directory.  Both of them are developed as modern web applications using modern Javascript tools.  A final grunt compile tool packages them up as a massive single string HTML text string that loads instantaneously in a web viewer with out the need for any export script steps.

I do not feel that either of those are painted into a corner.

Comment: What I will say is that you are better off developing these types of apps with the right tools ie a good JavaScript IDE and debugger etc.  That is very helpful and I would call that a "best practice".  

How the final product is deployed to the web viewer is a secondary question, and it depends on other factors.  For example if you want to deploy on WebDirect, you can't use the temp directory approach. If you want to update the data without forcing the web app to update, you need to use the temp directory.

Comment: Todd, whatever n% (where n is at most a small single digit integer) we might differ on, I whole-heartedly agree with everything you say in your last comment. For most developers I see, not exporting to the temp directory typically equals getting trapped in FileMaker, and that's very unfortunate indeed. I totally get that you're using a fully modern grunt-based process that avoids all these pitfalls, and I have no doubt that your grunt-based process would be included in whatever we might agree represents modern best practices here. With that said, I'll sign off now :-)